# React native text going off my screen, refusing to wrap. What to do?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, flexbox

The following code can be found in [this live example](https://rnplay.org/apps/dN8pPA)

I've got the following react native element:

```
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var {
  AppRegistry,
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
} = React;

var SampleApp = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return      (
  <View style={styles.container}>

        <View style={styles.descriptionContainerVer}>
          <View style={styles.descriptionContainerHor}>
            <Text style={styles.descriptionText} numberOfLines={5} >
              Here is a really long text that you can do nothing about, its gonna be long wether you like it or not, so be prepared for it to go off screen. Right? Right..!
            </Text>
          </View>
        </View>

        <View style={styles.descriptionContainerVer2}>
          <View style={styles.descriptionContainerHor}>
            <Text style={styles.descriptionText} numberOfLines={5} >Some other long text which you can still do nothing about.. Off the screen we go then.</Text>
          </View>
        </View>



  </View>);
  }
});
AppRegistry.registerComponent('SampleApp', () => SampleApp);
```

with the following styles:

```
var styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container:{
        flex:1,
    flexDirection:'column',
        justifyContent: 'flex-start',
        backgroundColor: 'grey'
    },
    descriptionContainerVer:{
    flex:0.5, //height (according to its parent)
    flexDirection: 'column', //its children will be in a row
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
    // alignSelf: 'center',
  },
  descriptionContainerVer2:{
    flex:0.5, //height (according to its parent)
    flexDirection: 'column', //its children will be in a row
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'orange',
    // alignSelf: 'center',
  },
  descriptionContainerHor:{
    //width: 200, //I DON\'T want this line here, because I need to support many screen sizes
    flex: 0.3,  //width (according to its parent)
    flexDirection: 'column',    //its children will be in a column
    alignItems: 'center', //align items according to this parent (like setting self align on each item)
    justifyContent: 'center',
    flexWrap: 'wrap'
  },
  descriptionText: {
    backgroundColor: 'green',//Colors.transparentColor,
    fontSize: 16,
    color: 'white',
    textAlign: 'center',
    flexWrap: 'wrap'
  }
});
```

This results in the following screen:

[image: Text off screen app]

**How can I stop the text from going off the screen and keep it confined in the middle of the screen with a width of i.e. 80% of the parent.**

I don't think I should use `width` because I will be running this on MANY different mobile screens and I want it to be dynamic, so I think I should rely totally on `flexbox`.

(That was the initial reason why I had `flex: 0.8` within the `descriptionContainerHor`.

What I want to achieve is something like this:

[image: What I want to achieve]

Thank you!

Answer (score 245, accepted):

The solution to that issue is `flexShrink: 1`.

```
<View
    style={{ flexDirection: 'row' }}
> 
   <Text style={{ flexShrink: 1 }}>
       Really really long text...
   </Text>
</View>
```

Depending on your set up, you may also also need to add `flexShrink: 1` to the `<View>`'s parent as well, to get this to work, so play with that and you'll make it.

The solution was discovered by [Adam Pietrasiak](https://github.com/pie6k) in [this thread.](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1438#issuecomment-336455742)

Comment: Parent view was also the solution for me! If parent had flexDirection: 'column', text refused to wrap.

Answer (score 515):

*I found solution from below link.*

[*[Text] Text doesn't wrap #1438*](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1438)

```
<View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}> 
   <Text style={{flex: 1, flexWrap: 'wrap'}}> You miss fdddddd dddddddd 
     You miss fdd
   </Text>
</View>
```

[image: Output]

*Below is the Github profile user link if you want to thank him.*

[Ally Rippley](https://github.com/a11y1337)

---

**Edit: Tue Apr 09 2019**

*As @sudoPlz mentioned in comments it works with `flexShrink: 1` updating this answer.*

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's a great answer, but I've tried it and for some reason it doesn't always work ( no idea why :S). flexWrap is a bit flaky in react-native.
+1 though for bringing that up.

Comment: ^^^ This is the actual answer here. Accept this Op!

Comment: Just note the info part of this answer https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1438#issuecomment-278745825

Comment: I discovered that in some cases `flexShrink: 1` applied to the parent view will help too.

Comment: I was dealing with a custom card component, and these solutions didn't work. For me  it was necessary to define a constant width size to my content container (I use `Dimensions` width).

Comment: flexShrink: 1, then some padding to the Text and that does the job

Comment: Applying ```flexShrink: 1``` to the parent of the ```<Text/>``` container worked for me!

Comment: Only flexShrink worked for me

Answer (score 116):

This is [a known bug](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1438).  `flexWrap: 'wrap'` didn't work for me but this solution seems to work for most people

**Code**

```
<View style={styles.container}>
    <Text>Some text</Text>
</View>
```

**Styles**

```
export default StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        width: 0,
        flexGrow: 1,
        flex: 1,
    }
});
```

Comment: just took me the day to found your answer...Thanks!

Comment: My android emulator was freezing for good when the single line text was going out of bonds. It was a terrible bug to find and to fix (this not-so related SO question was the only thing I found). This seems to have fixed it, a container with {flexGrow: 1, flex: 1} and the text with {flex: 1}.

Comment: this works for me on "react-native": "0.68.2"

Answer (score 59):

you just need to have a wrapper for your `<Text>` with flex like below;

```
<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
  <Text>Your Text</Text>
</View>
```

Comment: Thats the only proper solution which actually works as well

Comment: Indeed, `flex: 1` is all you need.

Comment: What if you don't want your text to occupy all the available space ?

Comment: Only `<Text style={{ flex: 1 }}>` without the additional `<View>` works as well for me.

Comment: This worked for me with big texts. With small texts, tough, it added spaces. `flexShrink: 1` solved it for me in both cases.

Answer (score 47):

This worked for me

```
<View style={{flexShrink:1}}>
  <Text>some long random text...</Text>
</View>
```

Comment: i have complex structure, for some reason, this works, other answer does not haha

Comment: On all of the solutions, this one only worked for me

Answer (score 43):

Most of the times, we see this problem when using `flexDirection: 'row'` because in other case, it is handled properly.

Anyway, here are the two ways to wrap the text properly;

**FIRST METHOD:**

To wrap the text to next line and not leave the display, we can do so by restricting the width of the `<Text>`;

```
<Text style={{width: "60%"}}>some long text goes here ...</Text>
```

The above code will restrict the width of the text to 60% of the available width and if the whole text doesn't fit in that, it will wrap itself, i.e, remaining text will move to next line and so on.

**SECOND METHOD**

set `flexShrink: 1` on both text element as well as its parent element which is wrapping it.

e.g,

```
<View style={{ flexShrink: 1, justifyContent: 'space-between', alignItems: 'center', flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
    <Text>First long string which goes long....</Text>
    <Text style={{flexShrink: 1}}>This is a long long text which must go out of the screen if we dont style it properly and not do some logic here</Text>
</View>
```

Other styles are just to show that result is working properly. `flexShrink: 1` is the only thing which you need.

Answer (score 14):

Another solution that I found to this issue is by wrapping the Text inside a View. Also set the style of the View to flex: 1.

Answer (score 14):

I had this same issue and to fix it I had to make sure ALL View parents had style={{flex: 1}}

Comment: This is the answer your looking for.

Answer (score 13):

It works if you remove `flexDirection: row` from `descriptionContainerVer` and `descriptionContainerVer2` respectively.

**UPDATE (see comments)**

I made a few changes to achieve what I think you're after. First of all I removed the `descriptionContainerHor` component. Then I set the `flexDirection` of the vertical views to `row` and added `alignItems: 'center'` and `justifyContent: 'center'`. Since the vertical views are now in fact stacked along the horizontal axis I removed the `Ver` part from the name.

So now you have a wrapper view that should vertically and horizontally align it's content and stack it along the x-axis. I then simply put two invisible `View` components on the left and right side of the `Text` component to do the padding.

Like this:

```
<View style={styles.descriptionContainer}>
  <View style={styles.padding}/>
    <Text style={styles.descriptionText} numberOfLines={5} >
      Here is a really long text that you can do nothing about, its gonna be long wether you like it or not, so be prepared for it to go off screen. Right? Right..!
    </Text>
  <View style={styles.padding}/>
</View>
```

And this:

```
descriptionContainer:{
  flex:0.5, //height (according to its parent),
  flexDirection: 'row',
  backgroundColor: 'blue',
  alignItems: 'center',
  justifyContent: 'center',
  // alignSelf: 'center',
},
padding: {
  flex: 0.1
},
descriptionText: {
  backgroundColor: 'green',//Colors.transparentColor,
  fontSize: 16,
  flex: 0.8,
  color: 'white',
  textAlign: 'center',
  flexWrap: 'wrap'
},
```

Then you get what I believe you were after.

**FURTHER IMPROVEMENTS**

Now if you would like to stack multiple text areas within the blue and orange views you can do something like this:

```
<View style={styles.descriptionContainer2}>
  <View style={styles.padding}/>
  <View style={styles.textWrap}>
    <Text style={styles.descriptionText} numberOfLines={5} >
      Some other long text which you can still do nothing about.. Off the screen we go then.
    </Text>
    <Text style={styles.descriptionText} numberOfLines={5} >
      Another column of text.
    </Text>
  </View>
  <View style={styles.padding}/>
</View>
```

Where `textWrap`is styled like this:

```
textWrap: {
  flexDirection: 'column',
  flex: 0.8
},
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Ok I changed the question a bit to reflect what I really wish to achieve. 
Now about the answer: The reason I used `flexDirection: row` was because (if I have this right in my head) `flexDirection` dictates the direction that the 'children' of that parent will be stacked at. 
Now I wanted the **text** to be the **middle child** in a parent that stacks children in a row, and occupy the 80% of the parents width (something like the second photo). Could you please update the answer a bit to reflect that?  I'm willing to accept this as the answer.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, been busy. But I've updated my answer, hope this is what you needed.

Comment: This answer is ABSOLUTELY amazing.. Exactly what I've been looking for, thanks Elliot !!!!!

Comment: `flexDirection: "row"` was the core of my problem, tried everything else without luck. Change your `flexDirection` to `column` and the text inside it will wrap normally.

Answer (score 12):

```
<View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}> 
  <Text style={{flex: 1, flexWrap: 'wrap'}}>
```

This will work

Comment: Flexwrap is unnecessary.

Answer (score 9):

I tried many of the answers above but none worked for me.
I achieved the best result by putting `flexShrink` on the `Text` element itself and `flexGrow` on both the parent `View` and the `Text` element.

I needed `flexDirection: row` on the parent because I want to have an icon on the right

```
<View style={flexDirection: 'row', flexGrow: 1}>
    <Text style={
        flexGrow: 1, 
        flexShrink: 1, 
        paddingLeft: 16,
        paddingRight: 8,
        alignItems: 'center',
    }>
        A long text that needs to wrap into multiple lines
    </Text>
</View>
<Image source={rightArrow}/>
```

It looks like this:

[image: Screenshot of text wrapping into multipple lines]

Answer (score 3):

I wanted to add that I was having the same issue and flexWrap, flex:1 (in the text components), nothing flex was working for me.

Eventually, I set the width of my text components' wrapper to the width of the device and the text started wrapping.
`const win = Dimensions.get('window');`

```
<View style={{
  flex: 1,
  flexDirection: 'column',
  justifyContent: 'center',
  alignSelf: 'center',
  width: win.width
}}>
  <Text style={{ top: 0, alignSelf: 'center' }} >{image.title}</Text>
  <Text style={{ alignSelf: 'center' }}>{image.description}</Text>
</View>
```

Answer (score 3):

In version 0.62.2 of React Native, i just put "flex-shrink: 1" in Container of my "Text", but remember the flex-direction:row in View of container. Thank you guys for the help.

My code:

```
export const Product = styled.View`
  background: #fff;
  padding: 15px 10px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  flex-direction: row;
`;

export const ProductTitleContainer = styled.View`
  font-size: 16px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  flex-shrink: 1;
`;

export const ProductTitle = styled.Text`
  font-size: 16px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
`;
`;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use height: 'auto' in text style.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think you can do something like this, I have attached a picture with code for a better idea:

[image]

So, we can do something like this:

```
TermsOfService = {
  fontFamily: 'Verlag-Book';
  fontSize: 14px;
  textAlign: center;
},
HighlightedText = {
  font-family: 'Verlag-Book';
  font-size: 14px;
  text-align: center;
  color: ${COLORS.PRIMARY_ADMIRAL_BLUE};
},
Container: {
  width: 100%;
  alignSelf: center;
  alignItems: center;
  justifyContent: center;
  flexDirection: row;
  flexWrap: wrap;
}
```

And is your Component just use it like this:

```
 <View style={Container}>
   <Text style={TermsOfService}>By joining, you agree to the some thing </Text>
   <Text style={HighlightedText}>this is highlighted </Text>
   <Text style={TermsOfService}>and </Text>
   <Text style={HighlightedText}>and this as well</Text>
 </View>
```

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> <View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}> 
>    <Text style={{ flex: number }}> You miss fdddddd dddddddd 
>      You miss fdd
>    </Text>
> </View>
> ```

{ flex: aNumber } is all you need!

Just set 'flex' to a number that suit for you. And then the text will wrap.

Comment: Strangely enough this actually was the fix that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Non of the answers work for me, so I decided to use a hack, which is to split the text by whitespace and render each of the word separately.

Although it's a hack, the upside is that I don't have to worry so much about messing up the wrapping due to the parent's container style.

```
// This code is written in Typescript
import React from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, View, Text } from 'react-native'
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
    flexDirection: 'row',
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    paddingVertical: 8,
  },
})

export const WrapText: React.FC<{
  text: string
}> = ({ text }) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {text.split(' ').map((word, index) => (
          <Text key={index}>
            {word}{' '}
          </Text>
        ))}
    </View>
  )
}

const Example = <WrapText text="Hello this is a working hack that wraps your text."/>
```

P/S: Of course this only works for alphabetical writing systems, other writing systems that does not utilise spaces (e.g. Chinese writings) will not wrap using this  component.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately none of the above worked for me.

I found this npm package you could use the package directly:
https://github.com/Bang9/react-native-wrapped-text

Or create something similar like this:

```
<View style={{ alignItems: "center", alignSelf: "center", width: "100%" }}>
  <View style={{ flexDirection: "row", flexWrap: "wrap"}}>
    <Text style={{ textAlign: "center"}}>Long text, sooo looong...</Text>
  </View>
</View>
```

Based on :
https://github.com/Bang9/react-native-wrapped-text/blob/master/src/index.js

Answer (score 1):

Tried everything nothing worked but this ->

```
wrapText:{
    width:"65%"
},
listItemLeft:{
    fontWeight:"bold",
    margin:3
},

<View style={styles.wrapText}>
    <Text style={styles.listItemLeft}>{item.left}</Text>
</View>
```

Answer (score 1):

Text overflowing code:

```
<View className="flex-row rounded-xl items-center p-2 pl-3 bg-red-400/20 space-x-2">
  <OrangeCircleIcon className="w-10 h-10" />
  <CText className="font-app-bold opacity-80">
    This is a Free Trial so you will not get charged anything now
  </CText>
</View>
```

Text not overflowing container code:

```
<View className="flex-row rounded-xl items-center p-2 pl-3 bg-red-400/20 space-x-2">
  <OrangeCircleIcon className="w-10 h-10" />
  <View className="flex-1"> {/*  Notice this addition */}
    <CText className="font-app-bold opacity-80">
      This is a Free Trial so you will not get charged anything now
    </CText>
  </View>
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<SafeAreaView style={{flex:1}}>
  <View style={{alignItems:'center'}}>
    <Text style={{ textAlign:'center' }}>
      This code will make your text centered even when there is a line-break
    </Text>
  </View>
</SafeAreaView>
```

Comment: Please comment your code and explain your answer

Answer (score 0):

I came here as I was searching for a solution to break / wrap words that are very long. I found a solution and that is to use 'wordBreak' prop inside <Text's 'style' prop. Using wordBreak:break-word solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

For a more sustainable approach for your app, use a component to render special texts that needs to be wrapped

```
// WrappedText.js Component
import { SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, Text } from "react-native";

const WrappedText = (props) => {
  const { children, textWrapperStyle={}, longTextStyle={} } = props;

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={[styles.textWrapper, textWrapperStyle]}>
      <Text style={[styles.longText, longTextStyle]}>{children}</Text>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  textWrapper: { flexDirection: "row" },
  longText: {
    flex: 1,
    flexWrap: "wrap",
  },
});

export default WrappedText;
```

Usage of component anywhere

```
<WrappedText longTextStyle={{ color: "blue" }}>{longText}</WrappedText>
```

Comment: I thought `SafeAreaView` is supposed to be used as a (full screen) parent view. What if that text is not a child of a full screen component?

I would imagine that to look weird and not behave properly.

Answer (score -1):

my solution below:

```
<View style={style.aboutContent}>
     <Text style={[styles.text,{textAlign:'justify'}]}>
        // text here                            
     </Text>
</View>
```

style:

```
aboutContent:{
    flex:8,
    width:widthDevice-40,
    alignItems:'center'
},
text:{
    fontSize:widthDevice*0.04,
    color:'#fff',
    fontFamily:'SairaSemiCondensed-Medium'
},
```

result:
[[image: d]my result[1]]

Comment: So you're using a static width on the parent, which is exactly what we wanted to avoid here.

Answer (score -4):

try to use this prop ***adjustsFontSizeToFit={true}*** in text component like this.

```
<Text adjustsFontSizeToFit={true}>
```

Comment: this makes the text size smaller, it doesn't wrap the text, which is what was the intention of the question.