# React Native iOS Text Sometimes Doesn't Wrap

Tags: ios, iphone, reactjs, react-native

I'm working on a React Native app and have run into some bizarre issues with  text not wrapping appropriately. This text wrap issue only occurs on certain simulators (iPhone 6+/7+/8+/X). Basically my app has a design that looks as follows:

```
<ScrollView
        style={styles.container}
        contentContainerStyle={styles.content}
>
    <Text style={styles.Text} >
          Blah blah blah blah ... Long long long long text
    </Text>
    <Text style={styles.Text} >
          Blah blah blah blah ... Long long long long text
    </Text>
    <Text style={styles.Text} >
          Blah blah blah blah ... Long long long long text
    </Text>
    {/* A bunch more Text components styled similarly as above */}
</ScrollView>
```

My styles are defined as follows:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
            container: {
                backgroundColor: '#F4F4F4',
            },
            content: {
                paddingRight: 5
            },
            text: {
                marginVertical: 8,
                paddingRight: 10,
                marginLeft: 16,
                fontSize: 18,
                lineHeight: 42,
            }
    }
```

Generally, the text wraps around correctly at the end of a text component. However, sometimes the end text will trail off the side of the screen:

[image]

When I switch to landscape mode, I can generally see the chopped off text, but I'm confused as to why this could be happening. I've tried every so many possible fixes, playing around with `flex`, `flexGrow`, `flexShrink`, `paddingRight`, `marginRight`, setting a width for the text component and/or contentContainerStyle, however nothing seems to work.

I've also referred to all of the following threads for possible fixes:

And none of the fixes seem to work. At this point I'm not even sure what else to try/how to go about tracking the possible source of error. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated!

[2]: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/17960   [3]: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/15114   [4]: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/7687   [5]: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1438   [6]: [React native text going off my screen, refusing to wrap. What to do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36284453/react-native-text-going-off-my-screen-refusing-to-wrap-what-to-do)

Comment: Did you try explicitly setting the container's `flexDirection` to `column`? That seems to work for some folks.

Comment: Yeah I've tried that to no success :( Another thing I've noticed is that when the text runs off the screen, there seems to be a blank line created after the text where the text should wrap to, but there is no text on the line. I've also seen instances where a certain phrase like "the cat" will just be squished into "thc" at the rightmost end of the screen.

Comment: I'm facing this exact same issue as well -- although I haven't pinpointed the cause, it looks like it most commonly occurs within a scrollview / flatlist, when the text component is not a part of the first item in the list.

Comment: Yeah it's really bizarre. I find that the text doesn't disappear when I change from portrait to landscape mode. Sometimes by switching the modes a few times it can actually behave correctly in portrait mode. Really strange.

Comment: I found out what causes the issue in our app. If the "Text Size" setting on iOS is set to a specific value, the text starts to behave strange - can you check my issue on github and try if this relates? https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/21007

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you need, you can use:
 
- numberOfLines: to truncate the text with an ellipsis after computing the text layout, including line wrapping, such that the total number of lines does not exceed this number. 
 - adjustsFontSizeToFit: to show all the text, perhaps with a new line. If use with numberOfLines - font should be scaled down automatically to fit given style constraints.
You can read more: [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/text)

Example:
`<ScrollView>
      <Text adjustsFontSizeToFit={true}>
            Blah blah blah blah ... Long long long long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text 
      </Text>
      <Text numberOfLines={1} >
            Blah blah blah blah ... Long long long long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text 
      </Text>
      <Text numberOfLines={1} adjustsFontSizeToFit={true}>
            Blah blah blah blah ... Long long long long text long text long text long text long text long text long text long text 
      </Text>
    </ScrollView>`