# React Native <Text> inside <Grid> <Col> is not wrapping

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I use react-native-easy-grid in a react-native app and I have a text element inside  element of . THe text seems to overflow out of the column but doesn't wrap around.

I have tried adding flexString, flexDirection, flexWrap properties as provided in other questions like [React native text going off my screen, refusing to wrap. What to do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36284453/react-native-text-going-off-my-screen-refusing-to-wrap-what-to-do) but it isn't working for Grid

```
    render() {
      return (
        <View>
          <Grid>
            <Row style={{ height: 50, padding: 10 }}>
               <Col><AntIcon name="warning" size={25} /></Col>
               <Col style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>
                 <Text style={{flex: 1, flexShrink: 1}}>
                 0 devices could not sync'd to cloud since you are not the owner.
                 </Text>
              </Col>
            </Row>
          </Grid>
        </View>
      );
    }
```

I expect the text "0 devices could not sync;d to cloud since you are not owner within the screen of the device" but its cut off and shows only partial string

Answer (score 0):

I realise what the issues was. it was the height parameter i have added that was messing it up

I made height 100 and it started working fine