# Is there a way I can wrap the whole contents of a Text component inside parent view in react-native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, textview

I am creating a screen in react-native where I have to display text on a parent view. How do I make the whole text be displayed?

At first I thought its a problem with text not wrapping, so I tried this solution from one question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36284453/react-native-text-going-off-my-screen-refusing-to-wrap-what-to-do)

```
<View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}> 
   <Text style={{flex: 1, flexWrap: 'wrap'}}> You miss fdddddd dddddddd 
     You miss fdd
     Another line
     and another one
   </Text>
</View>
```

I then tried `numberOfLines={1}`

This is my code

```
<View style={{ width: '100%', height: '15%', position: 'absolute', alignSelf: 'center', backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.4)', borderRadius: 5, marginTop: '90%', }}>
    <Text style={{ width: '80%', backgroundColor: 'transparent', alignSelf: 'center', textAlign: 'center', fontSize: 18, color: '#005F6A', marginTop: '5%' }}>
        {`Text the first &
        Text the second &
        text the third`}
     </Text>
</View>
```

I expect all text to be rendered but only the first line is rendered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Text is rendering correctly but as you have placed the property `width=80%` it's bounded to wrap the content to the new line. I have used the red color for parent view for more text clarity. Please try to run the below code and let me know if you face any issue. I will try to help you mate.

```
<View style={{ backgroundColor: 'red', borderRadius: 5 }}>
            <Text style={{  backgroundColor: 'transparent',
                            textAlign: 'center',
                            fontSize: 18,
                            color: '#005F6A',
                            marginTop: '5%'
                        }}>
                        Text the first & Text the second & text the third, Text the fourth & text the fifth
                    </Text>
                </View>
```

Comment: It works just fine but when I add `marginTop: '90%'` the text disappear altogether but the parent view remains

Comment: It should not disappear, I have also increased `marginTop` to 90% and text is still there. Albeit it increased the size of the parent's view which should be fine as Text needs some space to enlarge its space.

Comment: Yup you right I also put `flexDirection: 'row'` and everything is fine thanks