# Why my text don't wrap when I'm trying to decrease my size of div in react

Tags: html, css, reactjs, word-wrap

I don't understand but when I am trying to do it in simple html. The text is not overlapping in div but in reactjs it is overlapping. Here is my problem.

```
    const comments = [
        {uid:'1231BASDADA123',comment:"BoboBoboBoboBoboBoboBoboBoboBoboBoboBoboBoboBoboBoboBobo"},
        {uid:'1231BASDADA123',comment:"Bobo"},
        {uid:'1231BASDADA123',comment:"Bobo"},
        {uid:'1231BASDADA123',comment:"Bobo"},
        {uid:'1231BASDADA123',comment:"Bobo"},
        {uid:'1231BASDADA123',comment:"Bobo"},
        {uid:'1231BASDADA123',comment:"Bobo"},
        {uid:'1231BASDADA123',comment:"Bobo"},
        {uid:'1231BASDADA123',comment:"Bobo"},
        {uid:'1231BASDADA123',comment:"Bobo"},
        {uid:'1231BASDADA123',comment:"Bobo"},
        {uid:'1231BASDADA123',comment:"Bobo"},
        {uid:'1231BASDADA123',comment:"Bobo"},
        {uid:'1231BASDADA123',comment:"Bobo"},
    ]
   
/In my output function/
<div className="list">
     {props.comments.map((item,idx) => {
      return(
        <div className='user'>
            <div className="user-uid">
               <h6> {item.uid}</h6>
            </div>
            <div className="user-comment">
               <h5>
                 {item.comment}
               </h5>
         </div>
     </div>
     )
    })}
</div>
/My CSS/ 

.fandom .topic-comments .list {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    overflow: auto;
    background: linear-gradient(46deg,black,gray);
}

.fandom .topic-comments .list .user {
    width: auto;
    height: 50px;
    padding: 10px;
    background: black;
    color: rgb(201,198,52);
    border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(235, 231, 23);
}
```

Just don't mind the `.fandom .topic-comment` it doesn't have to do anything in this problem

So as you see in my first `comments` the longest comment overlaps to my `user-comment` and then I don't know how to fix it.. I try different variety of `flexShrink or flexDirection` in style base on this react native [Link] ([React native text going off my screen, refusing to wrap. What to do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36284453/react-native-text-going-off-my-screen-refusing-to-wrap-what-to-do)) and other stuff but the word doesn't really **WRAP MY TEXT** and I'm so done with this.. I always get this problem anywhere in my projects and I just do something like `<br/>` but I'm so sick of it I wanna wrap it on its own not doing some `<br/>`

Any idea how to fix this? This doesn't work in reactjs but when I try this in normal html it is working very well and I don't know why..

**UPDATE**
Here is the sample when my text is not much
[image]
Here is the sample when my text is a lot
[image]
I also tried this when `<textarea>` but still does the same thing in

**If this is not enought can you just give me guys a demo of how I will wrap my text in my div in react please? I badly hate this bug cause I always encounter this whenever my projects have a long text...the solution must be somehow related to mine....**

Comment: have you tried word-wrap: break-word ?

Comment: yes and it doesn't work too.

Comment: overflow-wrap: break-word?

Comment: still the same..

Comment: here you go done..

Comment: Where are you applyibng `word-wrap` or `overflow-wrap`? Your long comment is in `.user-comment > h5` but I see no css for that selection in your question.

Comment: oh yeah I already applied that in `.fandom .topic-comments .list .user-comment h5`

Comment: it is something like this 
```
.fandom .topic-comments .list .user-comment h5{
    word-wrap: break-word;
    width: 90px;
    font-size: 15px;
}

```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `word-wrap: break-word;` and `white-space: normal;` on `user-comment` to fix it

```css
.fandom .topic-comments .list {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  overflow: auto;
  background: linear-gradient(46deg, black, gray);
}

.fandom .topic-comments .list .user {
  width: auto;
  height: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: black;
  color: rgb(201, 198, 52);
  border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(235, 231, 23);
}

.fandom .topic-comments .list .user .user-comment {
  word-wrap: break-word;
  white-space: normal;
}
```

```html
<div class="fandom">
  <div class="topic-comments">
    <div class="list">
      <div class='user'>
        <div class="user-uid">
          <h6>1231BASDADA123</h6>
        </div>
        <div class="user-comment">
          <h5>
            BoboBoboBoboBoboBoboBoboBoboBoboBoboBoboBoboBoboBoboBoboBoboBoboBoboBoboBoboBoboBoboBoboBoboBoboBoboBoboBoboBobo
          </h5>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you share your full styles in CSS with me? I may can find some hints from there @MYTH

Comment: Ok I'll show the full codes

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-jennings-giyqef?file=/src/styles.css
just adjust the images cause I can't upload it lol..Btw thank you for helping me..

Comment: Hmm, your question and your sandbox code are different though. Which part in the sandbox you're having that problem? @MYTH

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-jennings-giyqef?file=/src/App.js 
here sir is the updated @Nick Vu

Comment: Just try to click the `Topic button` and then click the `box items` and then something will pop up..

Comment: I cannot click on `Topic` button, did you miss some code there? @MYTH

Comment: No I mean the topic..The topic word itself click it..

Comment: the topic or the button of topic..something was offload there...its working on mine fine.

Comment: I found your problem, you need to have `white-space: normal;` on that `use-comment` too. You can check my updated answer for it, @MYTH

Comment: btw can you explain sir why do I have to use `white-space` ?

Comment: You can read [this document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space) and try [this demo](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_text_white-space) for a better understanding. The default value is `white-space: normal` but I think you're using `white-space: nowrap;` on other elements that was causing problems @MYTH